# React JS Hooks: button for display data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so im trying to have a button where the user by pressing it, will display on the screen some fetched data from an API.
so far so good i fetched the data and when press the button it prints the result.
but i want to create one more button, where if the user press, it will print a random json data from the API every 3 seconds(like random quotes), right now i just have it just by pressing once and get one random solid displaying.
is there a way with hooks on how to do it?
Edit: the problem that i encounter is that it prints no matter what the user press, if he press to get one joke it always changes, and i dont want that.

first button that i have

```
<button id="button" onClick = {getQuote}>Get one quote</button> <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: quote}} />
```

and the second button/toggle(for start stop) bellow for getting/appearing a random joke every 3 seconds on screen

```
<button id="button" onClick = {handleGetT}>{isActive ? 'Get quotes' : 'Stop'}</button> <h3>{isActive ? null : quote}</h3>
```

Comment: its like i dont want to change the state, when the user is clicking the one quote, if he clicks multiple then state change

Comment: Can you please show the click handler of the button?

Comment: sure @Ravi <button id="button" onClick = {getQuote}>Get one quote</button>
      <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: quote}} />

Comment: @Ravi is getting the one quote but its refrshing every 3 seconds the state, and i want to have an other button where i will just show the refreshed every 3 seconds random quote. but the first output i want it to be one only every time he click

Comment: @Ravi and my second button click handler is that, for getting randoms every 3 seconds and for stopping getting on screen <button id="button" onClick = {handleGetT}>{isActive ? 'Get quotes' : 'Stop'}</button>
        <h3>{isActive ? null : quote}</h3>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.